# Video Indexer supported languages

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I want to know what languages are supported by the video indexer;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/language-identification-model -- here it lists 9.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/multi-language-identification-transcription -- here its 4

https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/docs/services/Operations/operations/Get-Video-Index? -- and here its 57.

So what is it? It's so confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the languages supported by video indexer is 12 languages:

[English,  Spanish,  French,  German,  Italian,  Mandarin Chines,
Japanese, Russian, Portuguese (Brazilian), Arabic (Modern Standard
and Levantine), Hindi, Korean]

If you upload a video without specifying the language or select auto detect, it will work fine if the video has one spoken language of the first 9 languages.

If the video is in the last 3 languages, you need to select the language when you upload the video.

If the video has more than one spoken language (max 3) and the languages among these 4 languages (English, French, German, Spanish), it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

If you check the links you post:

1-identifies which language is being spoken in your video

2-identifies which language is being spoken in your video, assuming it contains more than one language, it can identify only between those 4

3-(if I understood this one), it can translate the insights of the video to one of those 57, however, initially it needs to be one of those listed on 1.